# Making Warming hand sanitizer at home

Tags: reaction-mechanism

What can I  mix with hand sanitizer to make it heat up as I apply to/rub into my hands?  Something that doesn't affect the sanitizing.

Comment: Sanitizer is 95% alcohol: Adding something that can make it heat up would only evaporate more of the alcohol, neutralizing all sanitizing effects.